# Arguments with @BatchMapping in GraphQL Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

In Java Spring Boot with BatchMapping, I was wondering how to access the arguments. Below is parts of the schema:

```
type Query {
    user(username: String!): User
}


type User {
    username: String!
    posts: [Post!]!
}

type Post {
    upvotes: [User!]!
    upvoted(username: String!): Boolean
}
```

and the resolver looks like this:

```
@SchemaMapping
public Boolean upvoted(@Argument String username) {
        //...
}
```

but if I want to improve efficiency because of the n + 1 problem, I would do something like:

```
@BatchMapping
public Map<Post, Boolean> upvoted(List<Post> posts) {
      // ...
}
```

I am not sure how to access the argument "username" in order to query the database, such as in a query like this:

```
{
 user(username: "1") {
    posts {
      upvoted(username: "2")
    }
  }
}
```